# Center objects (divs) vertically and horizontally with wrap without big gaps

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

I have a problem with centering horizontally and vertically with wrapping divs (blue frame) in one big div (green frame, height 100%).
I was advised to use the `flex` display, but there were big spaces between the lines and I want the objects to only have the space between them that I set to separate them (i.e. `margin: 10px`).

[image]

The code is uploaded on codepen: https://codepen.io/misiekdp/pen/ZEWgagr
or see the working snippet here:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper h1 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#x1 {
  height: calc(100% - 58px);
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  /* padding: 5px; */
  /* position: relative; */
  /* transform: translateX(10%) translateY(50%); */
  position: absolute;
  /* top: 50% */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.jajucho {
  /* position: absolute; */
  /* display: block; */
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* display: flex; */
  /* position: absolute; */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Menu</h1>
  <div id="x1">
    <div class="jajucho">
    </div>
    <div class="jajucho">
    </div>
    <div class="jajucho">
    </div>
    <div class="jajucho">
    </div>
    <div class="jajucho">
    </div>
    <div class="jajucho">
    </div>
    <div class="jajucho">
    </div>
    <div class="jajucho">
    </div>
    <div class="jajucho">
    </div>
    <div class="jajucho">
    </div>
    <div class="jajucho">
    </div>
    <div class="jajucho">
    </div>
    <div class="jajucho">
    </div>
    <div class="jajucho">
    </div>
    <div class="jajucho">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are just a few changes you need to make this work:

**1. Wrap your `.jajucho` classes in a single container** so that we can vertically centre that container without spreading out it's contents, e.g.

```
<div id="x1">
    <div class="item-container">
        <div class="jajucho">
        </div>
        <!-- Rest of your divs here... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**2. Add `align-items: center;` to `#x1`** so that it will centre-align *vertically* (justify-content: center works horizontally only)

```
#x1 {
    align-items: center;
    /* Rest of your CSS...*/
}
```

**Note:** On a side note, you should change `height: calc(100% - 58px);` to **min**-height - otherwise it doesn't work properly if the screen is narrow and #x1 needs to be longer than the screen height.

**Working Example:**
Run the snippet and view it in Full Page so it's big enough to cee the centred content

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper h1 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#x1 {
  min-height: calc(100% - 58px);
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.jajucho {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Menu</h1>
  <div id="x1">
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="jajucho">
      </div>
      <div class="jajucho">
      </div>
      <div class="jajucho">
      </div>
      <div class="jajucho">
      </div>
      <div class="jajucho">
      </div>
      <div class="jajucho">
      </div>
      <div class="jajucho">
      </div>
      <div class="jajucho">
      </div>
      <div class="jajucho">
      </div>
      <div class="jajucho">
      </div>
      <div class="jajucho">
      </div>
      <div class="jajucho">
      </div>
      <div class="jajucho">
      </div>
      <div class="jajucho">
      </div>
      <div class="jajucho">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks bro! Everything works the way I wanted it to ;) And yes, I just wanted to use `height` to have a fixed window (scrolled inside).

[Correct project](https://codepen.io/misiekdp/pen/ZEWgagr)

Comment: @Michal Glad it worked for you! It wasn't clear that you had a scrollbar so I wasn't sure if you knew it might not fit vertically on all screens - no need for the min-height if you have a scrollbar! P.S. Not a bro by the way, I'm female :)